# Why isn't there a cite button in Mathematica stackexchange?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I have been using MMA stack exchange for almost 3 years and have benefited greatly from it. Sometimes, I even get useful algorithms in the answers which I would like to cite in my papers. But, unlike its contemporaries like [math](https://math.stackexchange.com) and [physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com) stack exchange, the MMA stack doesn't have a useful `cite` button.

This can be an issue. Sometimes, I have to ask the user for relevant sources instead of directly citing his answer.

I think having a `cite` button on the MMA stack exchange would also be better.

The scientific community would definitely find it useful.

To name some good examples, I would like to highlight these three:

1. [Poincare Section](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/296839/78049) algorithm by @[E. Chan-López](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/53427/e-chan-l%C3%B3pez).
2. [Lyapunov exponents](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/179470/78049) algorithm by @[Chris K](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/6358/chris-k)
3. [Predictor-Corrector](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/239786/78049) algorithm by @[Alex Trounev](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/58388/alex-trounev)

Comment: To answer the question in the title, please see [How come not all Stack Exchange sites have the cite option?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293384/how-come-not-all-stack-exchange-sites-have-the-cite-option).

Comment: Als: [How to properly cite someone on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/326762/how-to-properly-cite-someone-on-stack-exchange/326765).

Comment: @Domen I do agree with the answer that not all stack sites require a cite option but at least the ones with a technical resource pool like stack overflow or Mathematica stack exchange can have that, my point being if plain answer based stack sites like physics or math have cite option, why should coding based stack sites should be left alone? After all there are so many examples of answers which sometimes are so elaborate that they not only solve a small problem but also serve as an algorithm for many.

Comment: I don't disagree with you; I've just tried to provide you the answer to your question in the title :)

Comment: From Domen's link: "If a particular site thinks a feature would be useful to a majority of their audience, they're always welcome to create a site-specific feature request to have it enabled just for them." I don't doubt it will be useful for some of the users, but will it be useful for (close to) a majority of the users? Expanding your question to cover this could help on getting a decision made.

Comment: @Mast I think most of the users of Mathematica are either graduate students (even masters, PhDs, MPhils, PostDocs) or seasoned Researchers. In all these fields, scientific writing is regularly used, including plots/tables/charts, which are produced in Mathematica. Though some are easy, some require complex code, which many users take help with using stack exchange. So if the Physics or Math stack exchange can have a `cite` button, I think Mathematica being used in academia also makes it worthy.

Comment: I strongly agree with this feature request. I think it has not arrived in the heads of many users that these posts are archived with time stamps and thus _can_ be cited. Being afraid to be frowned upon and not knowing _how_ to cite them properly, many users will just tend to skip the citation without malicious intent. In short: If you mean people to do the right thing, then make it easy for them to do so.

Comment: For BibTex, you may use `@MISC {Question number,
    TITLE = {Question title},
    AUTHOR = {User ID/username (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/[user ID goes here])},
    HOWPUBLISHED = {Mathematica Stack Exchange},
    NOTE = {URL:https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/[question ID] (version: YYYY-MM-DD)},
    EPRINT = {https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/[question ID]},
    URL = {https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/[question ID]}
}`, which is just the same format as other sites you can cite.

Comment: @TymaGaidash, sure, that's a manual way. I hoped it would get automated by employing a `cite` button.